# Does fread() advances the pointer after it finishes reading the file?

Tags: c, file-handling

I'm trying to read from a file in C and after I'm done reading want to write to the same file. I'm trying to use fread() for this. Does anyone know if fread advances the pointer after it encounters "\0"? I mean after I finish reading do I need to advance the pointer or do I need to straight-away start writing into the file using fwrite ?

Comment: The file position is unpredictable if this is a text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fread` will advance the file position (not pointer) until it hits `EOF`.

However, it will not stop reading simply because it encounters `'\0'`. In fact, even `fgets` will only stop reading when it encounters `\n`. No standard library function I know of stops reading a file at `'\0'`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does advance the pointer unless you meet EOF or encounter an error:

> RETURN VALUES
>        The functions fread() and fwrite() advance the file position indicator for the stream by the number of bytes read or written.  They return
>        the number of objects read or written.  If an error occurs, or the end-of-file is reached, the return value is a short object count (or
>        zero).